# Struggling to designing proper ontology/vocabulary for foodstuff

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, vocabulary

I have foodstuff producers and want to publish information on the products they produce. I want each product (e.g. one chocolate bar) to be an individual, so I can apply some functions of my software to each piece of product.

The problem is, that I want each individual to show its ingredients but don't want to repeatedly write this information to each individual. E.g. particular chocolate bar "XY" has same ingredients like other chocolate bars "XY". Thus, I was thinking to make an owl class "Chocolate bar XY" where these information (ingedients) will be stored as properties of that owl class. But I'm not sure it's proper way.

Another idea I got is to make special class "Description of Foodstuff" and it's instance "Description of XY chocolate bar" which will be describing chocolate bar product and linked to each instance of chocolate bar "XY", but again I don't think it's a good solution.

What is the proper solution? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You've just given a specific example of the "inheritance versus composition" [argument](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose).

Either one will work.

I can't help but think that OWL and ontologies are 90s technologies that are rarely heard from anymore.  Is that because machine learning is in fashion, or were they not very helpful in addressing problems?

Doug Lenat has been at it for 30 years with [Cyc](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/600984/an-ai-with-30-years-worth-of-knowledge-finally-goes-to-work/).  Here's an article saying that it's only being applied now.  I don't see how it's going to overtake data and machine learning.  Why spend 30 years programming an ontology when the machine can take in terabytes of data every day and learn the space in real time?

Comment: You're right, what I'm interested in is, how this problem is in general solved in the semantic world? Whether information which instances share are stored at ontology classes, at the special "description" instance containing shared information or in some other way...

Comment: The ThoughtWorks article is very good. I'd recommend that you read it. I think it'll help.